# Opencv video in Flask application

Tags: python, opencv, flask, terminal, raspberry-pi

I'm trying run a face detection script in a Flask app running in apache 2 server in a Raspberry Pi 3 model B+.

Whenever I access the app from browser I'm getting this error:

```
******************************************************************
* FATAL ERROR:                                                   *
* This OpenCV build doesn't support current CPU/HW configuration *
*                                                                *
* Use OPENCV_DUMP_CONFIG=1 environment variable for details      *
******************************************************************
Required baseline features:
NEON - NOT AVAILABLE
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  OpenCV(3.4.4) /home/pi/packaging/opencv-python/opencv/modules/core/src/system.cpp:538: error: (-215:Assertion failed) Missing support for required CPU baseline features. 
Check OpenCV     build configuration and required CPU/HW setup. in function 'initialize'
[Tue Mar 03 14:20:36.611427 2020] [core:notice] [pid 776:tid 1995485424] AH00052: child pid 6966 exit signal Aborted (6)
```

But when running as a separate script it works fine. 
What will be the reason for above error here?

*`/videostream` route is registered using Flask blueprint in `index.py`*

**UPDATE:**
**It seems `import cv2` causes the error.**
**videostream.py**

```
import cv2
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, Response
videoStreamBp = Blueprint('videoStream', __name__)
# import the necessary packages
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
from imutils.video import FPS
import time

# initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (480, 320)
camera.framerate = 32
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(480, 320))

time.sleep(0.5)
fps = FPS().start()
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')

def gen(camera):
    # Video streaming generator function.
    while True:
        from camera_pi import Camera

        # capture frames from the camera
        for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
            # grab the raw NumPy array representing the image, then initialize the timestamp
            # and occupied/unoccupied text
            image = frame.array
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 5)

            for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
                cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
            # show the frame
            #cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + image + b'\r\n')
            key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

            # clear the stream in preparation for the next frame
            rawCapture.truncate(0)

            # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
            if key == ord("q"):
                break
            # update the FPS counter
            fps.update()
        # stop the timer and display FPS information
        fps.stop()
        print("[INFO] approx. FPS: {:.2f}".format(fps.fps()))

@videoStreamBp.route('/videoStream')
def getVideo():
    return Response(gen(Camera()),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all Raspberry Pi models support NEON. I have a Pi Zero W and have the same issue after installing OpenCV 4.

Comment: The error comes only when I'm running the script with Flask. If I run the program outside of Flask it works.

Comment: I have answered myself. Yo can suppress the error by following above steps.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it solved. Well Kinda solved. I suppressed the error in `/home/pi/packaging/opencv-python/opencv/modules/core/src/system.cpp`
Normal rebuilding Opencv with `Neon=ON` didn't help.
I have commented the Neon checking function at line `535-536` in `system.cpp` after building Opencv.
After that I had to follow these steps from [this tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/26/install-opencv-4-on-your-raspberry-pi/) to reinstall Opencv which is already built:

```
$ sudo make install
$ sudo ldconfig
```

It worked like a charm.